# How to run sparkR in 64-bit mode

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, rhadoop

I've install Spark - 1.4.1 (have R 3.1.3 version). Currently testing SparkR to run statistical models. I'm able to run some sample code such as,

```
Sys.setenv(SAPRK_HOME = "C:\\hdp\\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
#load the Sparkr library
library(SparkR)
# Create a spark context and a SQL context
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

#create a sparkR DataFrame
DF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, faithful)

sparkR.stop()
```

So Next,I'm installing `rJava` package in to `SparkR`. But its not installing. Giving below error.

```
> install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into 'C:/hdp/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/rJava_0.9-7.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset="utf-8"' length 898 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 898 bytes

Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'rJava/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Also when, I'm running `SparkR` command on shell it is started as 32-bit application. I highlighted the version info as below.
[image]

So, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce your 32-bit application. Have you tried using a vanilla R session and loading SparkR?

Comment: I haven't use vanilla R session. I'll  try by vanilla R session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was R version issue, previously i'm using R 3.1.3.That time it was giving me error, that the **rJava package is not available for current R version.**

```
To solve I follow this steps:
1) Installed new R version i.e R 3.2.2
2) Then update the Path variable and new R version path(Windows -> "Path" -> "Edit environment variables to for your account" -> PATH -> edit the value.)
3) Again restart sparkR shell.
```

[image]

Thanks all for your support!!!

Answer (score 2):

When in the `SparkR` shell, it seems to change where it installs R packages. The key line is

```
Installing package into 'C:/hdp/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib'
```

I suspect that

- You do not have write permission for `C:/hdp/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib'
- You don't want to put the package there in the first place.

You have two options,

- Start a vanilla R session and install as usual
- Or, use the `lib` argument in `install.packages` to specify where you want to install `rJava`